# Automating Instance Generation and Naming

Tags: java

I'm programming a Sudoku solver just to get myself back into the habit of using Java, and I'm running into a significant inconvenience.

I'm trying to build the necessary classes myself, so my general plan of attack is to have a Puzzle class that consists of an array of Row instances, an array of Column instances, and an array of Sector instances.  Each of these classes consists of an array that references the cells within that particular instance.   Upon construction, I plan on having the Puzzle class create all 81 Cells, and assign each one to the appropriate Row, Column, and Sector.  My question is two-fold:

First, how can I set it up such that each array references the Cells within it, so I can keep them in synch?  Just assigning them would create three unique instances of each class, which would have to be synched manually.  The alternate situation (unique Cells, each with a reference to a Row, Column, or Sector class) would make iterating through a Row impossible.

Second, how can I automate the process of generating and assigning the Cells?  I wanted to do something dynamic just to save the typing and code space - something along the lines of this:

```
private static final String[] letters{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I"};

for (String letter : Puzzle.letters){
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++){
        Cell "letter+j" = new Cell();
        "letter"[] = "letter+j";
        "j"[] = "letter+j";
        <Sector Calculation>
        "sector"[] = "letter+j";
    }
}
```

Obviously, that sort of thing doesn't work, but writing out 81 constructions and 243 assignments seems like a really stupid idea.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply use a 2 dimensional integer array (in this case `int[9][9]`) as data source - then  think about which indices indicate a row, a column or a sector. An oo-approach doesn't quite make sense here, it's just index-mapping-math that you will have to do.

Questions to ask yourself: Does a `Cell` do anything else than encapsulating an integer? Does a `Row`/`Column`/`Sector` do anything else than listing 9 Cells?

Comment: The solving algorithm I'm wanting to use involves tracking 9 "potentials" flags for each Cell, so I want to keep the Cell class intact.  I suppose I could create a Cell[9][9], but iterating through a sector would be a fair bit of extra effort.  Would you recommend an interface in this case to hide the implementation of iterating through a Row, Column, or Sector?

Comment: well, you've got 9 Sectors, the first ranging from row 0 to 2 and col 0 to 2, the next from row 0 to 2 and col 3 to 5 [...]. So there is a regularity involved, which makes it easy to iterate a single Sector

Comment: if u really want to have sector classes, you can just let each sector have a list of the relevant cells. however u'll still need to "iterate" once (to set things up). in any case, for the (m, n)th sector, a set of relevant coordinates is (3m+m', 3n+n'). a mapping from i -> m', n' is m' = i%3, n' = i/3. so one possible map from cell j of sector i would be (3(i%3)+j%3, 3(i/3)+j/3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would set it up (recently did this for a puzzle similar to Sudoku in some ways):

Create a PuzzleSquare class. Each square knows its coordinates, and has references to the squares to its left, right, top, and bottom.

Create a PuzzleGrid class. This class has (among other things) a 2-dimensional array which holds each of the squares in their corresponding coordinates, e.g. PuzzleGrid.grid[0][0] is the lower-left-hand PuzzleSquare.

This allows you to traverse rows and columns "logically" -- either by starting with a reference to a PuzzleSquare, and calling getLeft(), getRight(), etc. - or by directly referencing their coordinates in the PuzzleGrid. This seems like redundancy, and to some extent it is, but I found there are times where it's more convenient to ask a puzzle square to check its local neighbors instead of referring to them based on global coordinates.

Your second question, programmatic generation, should be an easy problem now that you can iterate through the entire grid based on global coordinates.

This is all overkill if all you are using the squares for is simple number storage, but you'll probably find (as I did) that it makes sense for squares to have logic in them, such as knowing whether their current value is valid, etc.